# Смещение вниз у элемента в Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

Писал уже об увеличивании всего в Mozilla. Проблему с этим решил, задал height и line-height. Но теперь возникла следующая проблема. Текст "test" выглядит везде нормально, но в Mozilla Firefox он почему-то смещается на 2 пикселя вниз...

```
#box_head {
 overflow: hidden;
 background: url('../images/box/box_head_bg.png') #3d3d3d;
 border-top: 1px solid #868686;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #3d3d3d;
 padding: 10px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 height: 15px !important;
 line-height: 15px !important;
}

<div id="box_head">test</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

эти два пикселя - Ваши верхняя и нижняя рамка. убедитесь в этом, уменьшив `padding` на `2px`, либо высоту элемента на `2px`.

Comment: @LeD4eG, почему в хроме всё нормально тогда?

Comment: Да, я тоже сталкивался с подобной проблемой. при создании кнопки, пришлось указать высоту и начались "скачки": в хроме нормально, в мозиле - на два пикселя ниже. Вызвано разницей расчёта высоты в этих браузерах.

Answer (score 2):

Что бы решить эту проблему нужно line-height задать не у блока #box_head, а у его родителя. Тогда все будет смотреться одинаково во всех браузерах.

Comment: а если нет у него родителя?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос. Если нет то можно задать =)